# Are Member Properties Let- or Use- Bound in F#?

Tags: f#

Consider the following example F# code:

```
type mytype() =
   member this.v = new OtherClass()
```

If OtherClass implements IDisposable, does the member binding act like a let binding or a use binding?  Is there any way to get it to act as a use binding?  I have some code very similar to this and I want to insure that the Dispose is called when the parent object goes out of scope.

A quick scan through *Expert F#* failed to turn up anything definite but perhaps I am looking for the wrong terms in the book.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your snippet, the body of the member `v` will be evaluated each time the member is called (meaning that it will create a new instance of `OtherClass` each time someone uses it). The member simply returns the newly created object and you could use it like this:

```
let m = new MyType()
use v = m.V // 'use' binding
```

I'm not sure if this is what you were asking though. If you want to create only a single instance, you'll need to write something like this:

```
type MyType() =
  let v = new OtherClass() 
  member this.V = v
```

This behaves as usual `let` binding and the `v` value won't be disposed automatically when the current instance of `MyType` is disposed. To have `v` automatically disposed, you'll need to implement `IDisposable` in `MyType` explicitly:

```
type MyType() =
  let v = new OtherClass() 
  member this.V = v
  interface IDisposable with 
    member x.Dispose() = (v :> IDisposable).Dispose()
```

Unfortunately, there is no syntactic sugar that would make it nicer (I once suggested allowing `use` and implicitly implementing `IDisposable` for type members to the F# team, but they didn't implement it
 (yet:-))).

Comment: Thanks Tomas.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks again for a well-informed and informative answer for an F# question.